# Syntax error with fragments on Menu Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have this code and I get an error in console that the  Component can't recieve fragments as children. How do I remove the fragments but keep the logic beacuse when I try to remove the fragments I get errros

```
{currentUser.level >= ACCESS_LEVEL.UNACTIVATED ? (
          <>
            {post.is_note_locked ?
              <MenuItem
                onClick={() => handleLockUnlock(LOCK_UNLOCK_TYPE.NOTE, false)}>
                {titles.lock_note}
              </MenuItem> :
              <MenuItem
                onClick={() => handleLockUnlock(LOCK_UNLOCK_TYPE.NOTE, true)}>
                {titles.unlock_note}
              </MenuItem>}
          </>
        )
          : null}`
```

I am expecting to not have fragments

Comment: Maybe wrap it in `<Menu>` instead of `<></>` fragments

Comment: Remove the fragments and the brackets around the second ternary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
 {currentUser.level >= ACCESS_LEVEL.UNACTIVATED ? (
    post.is_note_locked ? (
      <MenuItem
        onClick={() => handleLockUnlock(LOCK_UNLOCK_TYPE.NOTE, false)}
      >
        {titles.lock_note}
      </MenuItem>
    ) : (
      <MenuItem
        onClick={() => handleLockUnlock(LOCK_UNLOCK_TYPE.NOTE, true)}
      >
        {titles.unlock_note}
      </MenuItem>
    )
  ) : null}
```